# how to solve 'Server response (403): You are not allowed to store 'nester' package information?'

Tags: python

I'm a newbie of coding, and now I'm trying to study Python.

When I've registered on PyPI, and try to publish source code on it, the fault comes out:

```
Your selection [default 1]: 
1
Username: johncheung    
Password: 
Registering nester to https://pypi.python.org/pypi
Server response (403): You are not allowed to store 'nester' package information
```

What I've all done is followed by books. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package [`nester`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nester) already exists and you probably aren't the package owner. So you aren't allowed to publish new versions of it, as that could replace a known package with something else entirely.

As [Dietrich's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42455551/how-to-solve-server-response-403-you-are-not-allowed-to-store-nester-packa/42455780#42455780) says:

> If you don't have some original, useful code to publish, don't publish it. You can learn Python just fine without pushing to pypi.

If you just want to get your code out there, put it on GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket or a similar code hosting service. PyPI is only for when your code is really useful to a wider audience as a library installable by `pip`.

If you think that is the case:

If your package is unrelated, choose a different name.

If you want to change something about the existing `nester` package, see whether and how the respective project accepts contributions or ask the author about that.

Answer (score 2):

There is already a package called `nester`.  You don't own it, so you don't have permission to change it.

If you don't have some original, useful code to publish, don't publish it.  You can learn Python just fine without pushing to pypi.